# Paper.js use multiple moveTo commands on a path

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm trying to do:

[image: blue X]

Using this code:

```
var p = new Path();
p.strokeColor = 'blue'
p.strokeWidth = 4

var size = 10
var o = new Point(100, 100)

p.moveTo (o.add ([-size, -size]))
p.lineTo (o.add ([size, size]))
p.moveTo (o.add ([size, -size]))
p.lineTo (o.add ([-size, size]))
```

But instead I get:

[image: blue broken X]

Apparently the second `moveTo()` is ignored. How could I make it work? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in your case is to use `CompoundPath` instead of `Path` as you are intending to work on a group of paths.
There is a clue about that in the `path.moveTo` [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#moveto-point):

> On a normal empty Path, the point is simply added as the path’s first segment. If called on a CompoundPath, a new Path is created as a child and the point is added as its first segment.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/jZBBCoMwFESvErIxgkqErpSuvIDQQhfqIpqAouaHGC209O5NbC2Vbrr4hD8zeRlyx5KNAif41AvTtDjADXC3L0wjhY5IiivKYFQwS54z0xI/LXUpVTQZDb3IYABtY149zMLbWZeOm9Zah1V145hTdxNWjGm6KfB+JYdOGhJTGliX+p9bKhphEWcgEDHOSRE6RIDWo/K3OkMnvzKvyD6xp/wBCX8p9n9qLVivXNcJJ0X1eAI=) adapted from your initial code, demonstrating the solution.

```
var p = new CompoundPath();
p.strokeColor = 'blue';
p.strokeWidth = 4;

var size = 10;
var o = new Point(100, 100);

p.moveTo(o.add([-size, -size]));
p.lineTo(o.add([size, size]));
p.moveTo(o.add([size, -size]));
p.lineTo(o.add([-size, size]));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, and is the better solution in this case. They don't mention very obviously that Paths can't have gaps in them, apparently, but CompoundPaths can.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing:

```
var s = 10 // size

var o = new Point(100, 100)

var p1 = new Path.Line (o.add ([-s, -s]), o.add ([s, s]))
var p2 = new Path.Line (o.add ([s, -s]), o.add ([-s, s]))
p2.strokeColor = p1.strokeColor = 'blue'
p2.strokeWidth = p1.strokeWidth = 4
```

Which is inelegant, but works. I have tried `p1.unite (p2)` but that also doesn't work.